# Speeding up inference of Keras models

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, keras

I have a Keras model which is doing inference on a Raspberry Pi (with a camera). The Raspberry Pi has a really slow CPU (1.2.GHz) and no CUDA GPU so the `model.predict()` stage is taking a long time (~20 seconds). I'm looking for ways to reduce that by as much as possible. I've tried:

- Overclocking the CPU (+ 200 MhZ) and got a few extra seconds of performance.
- Using float16's instead of float32's.
- Reducing the image input size as much as possible.

**Is there anything else I can do to increase the speed during inference? Is there a way to simplify a model.h5 and take a drop in accuracy? I've had success with simpler models, but for this project I need to rely on an existing model so I can't train from scratch.**

Comment: How's your model architecture?

Comment: @FábioPerez very complex. VGG16 then a dual structure where both paths are 30 layers+ which are then concatenated at the end. It’s pretrained so afaik I can’t adjust the model structure.

Comment: The inference of VGG is slow due to the large fully-connected layer at the end. Use a faster net such as MobileNet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGG16 / VGG19 architecture is very slow since it has lots of parameters. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957758/604734).

Before any other optimization, try to use a simpler network architecture.

[Google's MobileNet](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/06/mobilenets-open-source-models-for.html) seems like a good candidate since it's [implemented on Keras](https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenet) and it was designed for more limited devices.

If you can't use a different network, you may compress the network with pruning. [This blog](http://machinethink.net/blog/compressing-deep-neural-nets/) post specifically do pruning with Keras.

Comment: It’s a pretrained network so I don’t have that option right?

Comment: Can't you reproduce the train on MobileNet? The weights are initialized with ImageNet weights. Otherwise, you will have to compress your network by finding the most impactful units. Check  https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00149 and https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/pruning-deep-learning

Comment: possible but it would take weeks of training and be pretty expensive. I’ll look into compression - thanks.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/Irtza/Keras_model_compression. I never tested this, but might be what you want.

Comment: great thanks. Accepted your answer - would be great if you could mention compression in the answer too.

Comment: Also, [this](http://machinethink.net/blog/compressing-deep-neural-nets/) might be of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html#) will help. OpenVINO is an [open-source](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino) toolkit for network inference, and it optimizes the inference performance by, e.g., graph pruning and fusing some operations. The [ARM support](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_contrib/tree/master/modules/arm_plugin) is provided by the [contrib](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_contrib) repository.

Here are the [instructions](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_contrib/wiki/How-to-build-ARM-CPU-plugin) on how to build an ARM plugin to run OpenVINO on Raspberry Pi.

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.